# git describe gives different output between local machine and GitHub Actions runner

Tags: git, github-actions

I have a test repo where I have a tag `v33.4.0` in a test branch. When I locally (Windows machine) call the command

```
git describe 26888c716fd70bde90c73ed603134bd1162018c6 --abbrev=7 --match="v33.4.*" --always
```

I get the following output:

```
v33.4.0-5-g26888c7
```

which is the expected output. Calling the same output on a docker `ubuntu:latest` machine gives me the same output which is also expected.

The situation now is this: I have a shell script which is running within a github actions workflow. I added `set -x` to that script to print the commands. The command which is shown is this on:

```
git describe 26888c716fd70bde90c73ed603134bd1162018c6 --abbrev=7 '--match=v33.4.*' --always
```

and this command gives me the output

```
26888c7
```

Here the full output:

```
++ git describe 26888c716fd70bde90c73ed603134bd1162018c6 --abbrev=7 '--match=v33.4.*' --always
+ git_response=26888c7
```

So, there is a difference between the result on a docker machine / my local Windows machine and the result in GitHub actions. Any idea why?

**Edit**

`git version` in each environment:

| GitHub runner | docker `ubuntu:latest` | Windows local machine |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `git version 2.41.0` | `git version 2.34.1` | `git version 2.41.0.windows.1` |

Comment: What version of `git` is running in each environment? With version 2.41.0 locally, the `--always` flag seems to behave as in your github script; the `--tags` flag results in output like what you're seeing locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The github action `actions/checkout` seems to checkout the repository without tags when there was only a push on a branch. When adding `fetch-depth: 0` to that action the tags are also fetched:

```
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
```

More information about this can be found in this issue: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/701